# Draconic Sorcerer Elemental Affinity with ongoing effects

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, sorcerer

The [Draconic Bloodline](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#DraconicBloodline) Sorcerer has the following feature:

> **Elemental Affinity**
> Starting at 6th level, when you Cast a Spell that deals damage of the type associated with your Draconic ancestry, you can add your Charisma modifier to one damage roll of that spell. At the same time, you can spend 1 sorcery point to gain Resistance to that damage type for 1 hour.

This reads that it would only apply to one damage roll of a spell, meaning that spells such as [Immolation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/immolation) and [Investiture of Flame](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/investiture-of-flame) would only benefit from the first damage roll of that spell.

Is this the correct assumption? If so, would it be too strong to rule that it applies on every separate instance of damage?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! I think that your question is a duplicate of these ones: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134088/63061, https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101077/63061 : there you can find the answer to yours. You could have a look at [tour] and at the [help] to have more guidance about how posting/searching Question&Answers. Welcome again and happy gaming!